# call function in the jframe from the jpanel class which was added on jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i have 1 jframe named frame, 1 jpanel within the jframe named mainpanel and 1 jpanel from another class named ControlPanel.

the jpanel ControlPanel was added inside the jframe frame's mainpanel.

```
private void onLoad(){
ControlPanel cpanel = new ControlPanel;
mainpanel.add(cpanel);
}
```

inside the jframe frame, i have a function:

```
public void hideComponents(){
//code here
}
```

since i've added the cpanel to the frame's mainpanel, how do i call a function in the frame from within the cpanel?

what i've done is declared the frame in the controlpanel class

```
private MainFrame frame;
```

then created a button calling the frame's function

```
frame.hideComponents(); // error occurs pointing here "NullPointerException"
```

Comment: your object not initialized..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the MainFrame class instance as parameter in ControlPanel constructor
an then call hideComponents method from there. Example goes here:

```
public final class ControlPanel extends JPanel {
    // Optional: you can even declare your MainFrame as private field member
    // if you want to keep track of the frame instance. But let's assume
    // you don't need that in your occasion

    public ControlPanel(MainFrame frame) {
          frame.hideComponents();
    }
    //maybe other code 
    ...
}
```

Example:

```
private void onLoad(){
  ControlPanel cpanel = new ControlPanel(MainFrame.this);
  mainpanel.add(cpanel);
}
```

Comment: how do i put it on a buttonClick from controlpanel?

Comment: you add a button in ControlPanel, use the option that a gave you on my answer, and declare/introduce your MainFrame as class field. Finally, you assign an onclickListener to your button in order to be able to hear the click events. In the method body of your clickListener you call the hideComponents method of MainFrame

Answer (score 0):

your object not initialized..

try

```
frame = new MainFrame();

frame.hideComponents();
```

Comment: i thought it's not working. but after reviewing my codes in hideComponents() function, seems I can't set the jPanel's visibility to false. why is that? but your code works. Thanks!